# Executing SSIS package using TSQL commands in visual studio

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, ssis, catalog, execute-sql-task

I am trying to execute the SSIS  package using TSQL commands (as a part of asynchronous execution testing) using Execute SQL task but I am getting error with related to server authentication and connection not being made.

*Error: 0xC002F210 at Execute SQL Task, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "Declare @execution_id bigint
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalo..." failed with the following error: "The operation cannot be started by an account that uses SQL Server Authentication. Start the operation with an account that uses Integrated Authentication.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.*
The TSQL commands I used in Execute SQL task with connection made to db by creating OLEDB connection with sql server authentication:

1. EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] with package details
2. EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] where I am setting package parameters
3. EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id starting the execution of package

Does this happen because I am trying to call SSISDB catalog stored procedures locally ie. from outside SSMS ? I also checked the users role on SSISDB and it has access to it. The TSQL commands work fine when executed from SSMS. Any leads would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Updated(Found the solution) : 2021-09-27**

I found the solution through other sources. I simply changed from sql server authentication for db connections to windows authentication and deployed the package to SSISDB and tested there. It worked fine. Locally I was not able to test with windows authentication,as my windows account did not have enough permission to db server.

Comment: SQL Statements don't work differently because you called them from a different application. You need to add more detail here other than "I get an authentication error."

Comment: sorry for that. I have added all the details to the question now. Also, I noticed now that when I test connection it succeeds but when I am trying to build TSQL commands for catalog SP calls it is showing as login failed. Please guide me what is that I am doing incorrectly.

Comment: Can you add an image of the SSIS data flow implementation @SpoorthiTejasvi

Comment: I found the solution through other sources. I simply changed from sql server authentication on connection to windows authentication and deployed the package to SSISDB and tested there. It worked fine. Locally I was not able to test as my windows account did not have enough permission on server.